# List environments in ArabLuaTeX

Tags: lists, luatex, arabic, bidi

I am new to ArabLuaTeX and wondering if and how to make list environments (such as itemize, enumerate, etc.) within `\begin{arab}` and `\end{arab}` I tried my best but could not figure out.

This works until the enumerate environment is added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{amiri}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\begin{document}

\begin{arab}

\begin{enumerate}
\item الأصل الأول منها في التوحيد
\item الأصل الثّاني في القدر
\item الأصل الثّالث في العدل
\item الأصل الرابع في الوعد والوعيد
\end{enumerate}

\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: this might be of some help perhaps.. http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/doc/latex/arabi/user_guide.pdf

Comment: arabluatex is a quite newest package. I suggest you to ask for new feature on http://issues.robertalessi.net/

Comment: For some reason, the call `\begin{enumerate}` causes LuaTeX to process `\begin {\txarb{eنُمeرَتe}}`

Comment: This is more a feature that has to be added in `arabluatex` than an actual bug.  I'll look into this tomorrow and will post a new release as quickly as possible.

Comment: @egreg yes, in such a case `arabluatex` tried to process `enumerate` so as to produce Arabic for list environments are not (yet!) implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for this report.

I have to confess that list environments have slipped my mind so far!  Very sorry about that.  The next release of `arabluatex`, which I hope to publish soon, will support such environments.

Meanwhile, the two environments `asparaenum` and `asparaitem` that are provided by the `paralist` package will get us out of trouble.

The following mwe works with `arabluatex` 1.4.5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{paralist}

% 'RawFeature={+anum}' is added below to have 'Indian numbers'
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\begin{document}


\begin{asparaenum}[.1] % '.1' for the dot to appear after the number
                       % in RTL mode.
  \begin{arab}
  \item{} الأصل الأول منها في التوحيد % '\item{}' mind the braces
  \item{} الأصل الثّاني في القدر
  \item{} الأصل الثّالث في العدل
  \item{} الأصل الرابع في الوعد والوعيد
  \end{arab}
\end{asparaenum}

\begin{asparaitem}
  \begin{arab}
  \item{} الأصل الأول منها في التوحيد
  \item{} الأصل الثّاني في القدر
  \item{} الأصل الثّالث في العدل
  \item{} الأصل الرابع في الوعد والوعيد
  \end{arab}
\end{asparaitem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

`arabluatex` 1.5 is out and should become available on the mirrors within the next 24 hours. Among the new features, en­vi­ron­ments and list en­vi­ronments are now pro­cessed in Ara­bic mode; uni­code Ara­bic in­put for short in­ser­tions and run­ning para­graphs as well is facilitated by the `\txarb` command and a new `txarab` environment.

To take one example, the following code will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% 'RawFeature={+anum}' is added below to have 'Indian numbers'
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\begin{document}


\begin{txarab}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item الأصل الأول منها في التوحيد
  \item الأصل الثّاني في القدر
  \item الأصل الثّالث في العدل
  \item الأصل الرابع في الوعد والوعيد
  \end{enumerate}
\end{txarab}

\begin{txarab}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item الأصل الأول منها في التوحيد
  \item الأصل الثّاني في القدر
  \item الأصل الثّالث في العدل
  \item الأصل الرابع في الوعد والوعيد
  \end{itemize}
\end{txarab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll post a note here when the next release of `arabluatex` is ready.

Comment: BTW, this issue has been reported here: http://issues.robertalessi.net/view.php?id=5 today.

Comment: I now have a way to make `arabluatex` work with list environments.  The next release of `arabluatex` should be out by the end of this week.

Comment: As promised, just a quick note: the next release of arabluatex is ready and I will upload it to CTAN tomorrow morning. I will also add here a new answer with a couple of examples.